# React-router <Route> tag not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm running into an issue where my route tag in specific is not rendering any components.

Steps I have tried:

- Changed import of { Route } from "react-router-dom".
- Changed paths to see if other paths render.
- Rendered the component within  tags (this worked).

The issue seems to be coming down to something going on with the  tag.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
import { Component } from "react";
//import all components rendered
import NavBar from "./Nav";
import Orders from "./Orders";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import Login from "./Login.jsx";
import Home from "./Home.jsx";
// for routing
import { Route } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

//main App to combine all components and be rendered
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <NavBar />
                <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

The versions are:

```
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.2.1
│ └── react-router@6.2.1 deduped
└── react-router@6.2.1
```

I tried changing the tags to  as per a suggestion and it still didn't work, but I may have implemented it incorrectly. Here is what I tried:

```
import { Component } from "react";
//import all components rendered
import NavBar from "./Nav";
import Orders from "./Orders";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import Login from "./Login.jsx";
import Home from "./Home.jsx";
// for routing
import { Route } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

//main App to combine all components and be rendered
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Routes>
                <NavBar />
                <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
            </Routes>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

The errors I am getting on the console are:

```
Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
    Choo 3
    React 17
    Choo 2
    Webpack 3
```

```
The above error occurred in the <Routes> component:

Routes@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:54433:7
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42:1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Solution:

Was resolved by switching the "component" tag to "element" tag and removing the  tag outside as follows:

```
            <>
                <NavBar />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" exact element={<Login />} />
                </Routes>
            </>
```

Comment: Which component isn't rendered? `Login` or `NavBar`?

Comment: Please verify what version of `react-router-dom` you have installed. From your project directory please run `npm list react-router react-router-dom` and report back. `Route` should certainly be imported from `react-router-dom`, but depending on version the component API is different.

Comment: Both components are not rendering, however NavBar will render if Route is not used. 

Here is the output of the npm list command:

react-router-dom@6.2.1
│ └── react-router@6.2.1 deduped
└── react-router@6.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- List item

put **Navbar** outside for **Routes** tag like i did below

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes,Route } from "react-router-dom";

//main App to combine all components and be rendered
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <>
            <NavBar />
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Login/>} />
            </Routes>
          </>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

also for newer version of **react-router-dom** use **element** instead of **component** and remove **exact**
It will be good if you use **BrowserRouter** index.js and wrapper App over there
for example index.js

```
<BrowserRouter><App/></BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: can you please share error or screenshot of error??

Comment: @LukeAnderson updated code above please review once more

Comment: Yes, I just posted it to the main post. The error when I change to the solution is: Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

Comment: in ```index``` file wrap ```App``` with ```BrowserRouter```

Comment: can you share your code in codesandbox will try to quickly fix

Comment: It returns this warning: Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

Comment: did you replace ```component={Login}``` with ```element={<Login/>}```

Comment: Here is the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-water-hse72?file=/src/index.js

 Thank you!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-glitter-y9ljk?file=/src/App.jsx
updated please check now @LukeAnderson

Comment: replace ```component={Login}``` with ```element={<Login/>}```
that was the issue as I commented above @LukeAnderson

Comment: Thank you! I saw that you changed the tag from "component" to "element" and added the tag inside it and it worked. I will post the solution to my main post.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and applied the fix. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on react router v6, you need to wrap all your routes in the Routes component from react-router-dom.

Comment: Except it looks like OP is using RRDv5 based on the `Route` props they are using. Let's wait for version confirmation before spit-balling solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, not sure if I implemented it correctly, but here is what I tried and it still isn't working. I imported it as "import { BrowserRouter, Routes}" and then wrapped what I wanted rendered in <Routes> tags instead of <BrowserRouter> tags.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import { Component } from "react";
//import all components rendered
import NavBar from "./Nav";
import Orders from "./Orders";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import Login from "./Login.jsx";
import Home from "./Home.jsx";
// for routing
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

//main App to combine all components and be rendered
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <NavBar />
                <Routes>
                   <Route path="/" element={<Login/>} exact/>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).